# ArgumentError in Rails::WelcomeController#index twitte bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I have been developing using rails 4 and ruby 1.9.3, I was using the twitter bootstrap tutorial from `http://railscasts.com/episodes/328-twitter-bootstrap-basics` and I am getting the following error now trying to load my app, can anyone help with this, I have tried variations of get "welcome/index" and root to: 'welcome#index' in my route.rb file.

Here are my welcome controller, framework trace, routes.rb and gem file:

Error message: ArgumentError in Rails::WelcomeController#index

/////Framework trace

```
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:89:in `initialize'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:89:in `new'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:89:in `action_methods'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/hide_actions.rb:36:in `action_methods'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/url_for.rb:25:in `action_methods'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:179:in `action_method?'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:230:in `method_for_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/hide_actions.rb:17:in `method_for_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:14:in `method_for_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:130:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:655:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__159494264__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

/////////Routes.rb

```
Myapp::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  #get "welcome/index"
  root to: 'welcome#index'
end
```

/////////Welcome controller

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

////////Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
#gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

gem "paperclip", :git => "git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"

gem 'protected_attributes'

gem 'will_paginate'

gem 'devise'

gem 'cancan'

gem 'less-rails'

gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'

gem 'therubyracer'

#gem 'libv8'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# group :assets do
  # gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
# end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have problems with twitter bootstrap, running in Ruby 2.0.
You can try in Ruby 2.0.